# alert() box is coming up multiple times in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am clicking on a simple add to cart button to add an item to a cart , if the item is already present it gives an error `item already` . all goes well , but when i click the button second time , i have to **close the alert box twice** , 3rd time i click , i have to **close the alert box thrice** and so on ... this goes on until i refresh the page , and same thing starts from scratch

jquery code :

```
 function add()
       {
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $('#addtocart').submit(function() {
           //$('#add-button').prop('disabled',true);
    var user = $('#user').val();
           var pid = $('#pid').val();
        $.ajax({
        type:       "post",
        url:        "/devilmaycry/register?action=addtocart",
        data:       {pid:pid ,user:user},
        success:    
                   function() 
                    {
                          alert("Item has been added to cart");
                },
                  error:
                     function(xhr) 
                    {
                         if (xhr.responseText=="already present")
                            alert("item is already present in cart"); 

                         else if(xhr.responseText=="error")
                             alert("item cannot be added , server error");
                } 
              });
              return false;
     //e.preventDefault(); 
   });

        });
       }
```

servlet code :

```
if(n.equals("addtocart"))
  {
      String user = req.getParameter("user");
      int pid = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("pid"));

      k=o.addintocart(user,pid);

     if(k==2)
      {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        pw.write("already present");
      } 
     else if(k==0)
      {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        pw.write("error");
      }
  }
```

error or success the **behavior is same** for both

Comment: Check whether your add method called multiple times?most likely error is where you have configured the event to trigger add

Comment: thnks man , got the ans ... i was using the `onclick()` and `$('#addtocart').submit(function()` simultaneously , my bad

Answer (score 1):

You only need this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#addtocart').submit(function() {
    //$('#add-button').prop('disabled',true);
    var user = $('#user').val();
    var pid = $('#pid').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/devilmaycry/register?action=addtocart",
        data: {
            pid: pid,
            user: user
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("Item has been added to cart");
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.responseText == "already present")
                alert("item is already present in cart");

            else if (xhr.responseText == "error")
                alert("item cannot be added , server error");
        }
    });
    return false;
    //e.preventDefault(); 
});});
```

No other event handlers required.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use it after completing submit.It will off the click event.

```
  $("#addtocart").off('click');
```